# button onclick not working on first click

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

my button.onclick doesn't work on the first click, but it works on the second.
I used an alert to check and even the alert doesnt work on the first click, but works on the second click.
here's the link to the app in case you need it - 
http://silentarrowz.imad.hasura-app.io/news
could you tell me what's wrong??
here's the code

```
window.onclick = function () {
    var displayNews = document.getElementById('currentNews');
    var newsButton = document.getElementById('getnews');
    newsButton.onclick = function () {
        alert('the button is clicked');
        var newsxr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        newsxr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (newsxr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && newsxr.status === 200) {
                var currentNews = JSON.parse(newsxr.responseText);
                var currentArticles = currentNews['articles'];
                var numberArticles = currentNews['articles'].length;
                var newsDisplay = '';
                var author;
                var title;
                var description;
                var urlToImage;
                for (var i = 0; i < numberArticles; i++) {
                    author = currentArticles[i]['author'];
                    title = currentArticles[i]['title'];
                    description = currentArticles[i]['description'];
                    urlToImage = currentArticles[i]['urlToImage'];
                    newsDisplay = newsDisplay + "<p>" + "<span class='title'>" + title + "</span>" + "<br>" + description + "<br>" + "<img src='" + urlToImage +
                        "'</img>" + "</p>";
                }
                alert('displaying the news now');
                console.log('current news is : ', currentNews);
                displayNews.innerHTML = newsDisplay;
            }
        }; //on state change
        newsxr.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=national-geographic&sortBy=top&apiKey=1af110441a8e4f72925f78344e58c2a4', true);
        newsxr.send(null);
    }; //button onclick function ends
}; // window onclick function ends
```

Comment: You wrapped the entire thing in `window.onclick` so you have to click the window at least once to make it work, and it just keeps on working, every time you click something, you keep adding more event handlers.

Comment: @adeneo, You are partially correct. The `newsButton.onclick` property allows one, and only one, event handler to be added.  Thus, the subsequent changes to that property do not add additional handlers; the older handler is replaced.

Comment: @Makyen - that's right, guess I'm used to `addEventListener`. It's still a bad idea.

Comment: @adeneo, I definitely agree that it is a bag idea (both using the `onclick` property and adding (anonymous) event handlers from within event handlers). While there are some situations where an argument could be made for using the `onclick` property using `addEventListener` should be preferred in most/almost all situations.  And, yeah, adding multiple identical-functionality anonymous functions as event handlers using `addEventListener`, particularly when added within another event handler, is a common error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth about your code is the following..

1. You are assigning an onclick event to the window. when you click the window it then gets the buttons id which then assigns an onclick event to your button.
2. Your button only works when you click anywhere in the window (your browser User interface). You can try it and see

SOLUTION

remove the on window.onclick event stuff.

this should be the only code you should be seeing in your editor to make things work.

```
var displayNews = document.getElementById('currentNews');
var newsButton = document.getElementById('getnews');
newsButton.onclick = function(){
    alert('the button is clicked');
    var newsxr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    newsxr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(newsxr.readyState ===XMLHttpRequest.DONE && newsxr.status ===200){
            var currentNews = JSON.parse(newsxr.responseText);
            var currentArticles = currentNews['articles'];
            var numberArticles = currentNews['articles'].length;
            var newsDisplay ='';
            var author;
            var title;
            var description;
            var urlToImage;
            for(var i=0;i<numberArticles;i++){
                author = currentArticles[i]['author'];
                title = currentArticles[i]['title'];
                description = currentArticles[i]['description'];
                urlToImage = currentArticles[i]['urlToImage'];
                 newsDisplay = newsDisplay + "<p>"+"<span class='title'>"+  title+"</span>"+  "<br>"+description+"<br>"+"<img src='"+urlToImage+"'</img>"+"</p>";
            }
            alert('displaying the news now');
            console.log('current news is : ',currentNews);
            displayNews.innerHTML = newsDisplay;
        }
    };//on state change

    newsxr.open('GET','https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=national-geographic&sortBy=top&apiKey=1af110441a8e4f72925f78344e58c2a4',true);
    newsxr.send(null);
};
//button onclick function ends
```

I hope this was explanatory

Comment: this was very well explained.
It was actually a silly mistake which I hadnt noticed even though I was looking at the code for quite a while. dont know why this happens!!

Comment: it happens a lot to me some times. Especially when we get lost in our work. You are welcome bro

Answer (score 1):

Because the first click is `window.onclick = function()` part which tells the window to define another click event only, and then the real click event will work when you click the second time.

Deleting the window click event already suffices.

P.S. I don't see why having window click event is meaningful in your code.

Comment: oh, no. How could I be so stupid. I meant to do window.onload

Comment: Was typing to slow... you got me

Comment: haha. yes. problem solved
By the way nice nickname you have there